# What does this mean?192.168.2.2 in use by d8:a2:5e:41:aa:6e, DHCP Server 192.168.2.1

Tags: mac-osx

What does this mean? It popped up on my computer: 192.168.2.2 in use by d8:a2:5e:41:aa:6e, DHCP Server 192.168.2.1

Answer (score 6):

Your IP address is 192.168.2.2, but that is also in use by another computer with the MAC address d8:a2:5e:41:aa:6e. Your DHCP server, which is 192.168.2.1, needs to be reconfigured because it is either handing out an IP address that is set manually on another device or it exists with another DHCP server and has the same scope as the other one.

Comment: It's not necessarily a misconfigured DHCP server.  If there are devices on the network using manually-configured IP's, that would also cause a conflict.  In that case the solution is usually to just use DHCP for everything.

Comment: Or, depending on the environment, find the offending device that was configured to conflict and terminate it with extreme prejudice.